# Regex to trim a url to the last folder

Tags: regex

If I have a url like: http://example2.com/foo/biz?asdf=qwer (or even more depth)

I want to trim it to the last folder: http://example2.com/foo/

I also want it to pass if there is no folder: (ie: http://example.com) would just be unmodified, but still match.

Comment: Why not use an actual URL parsing library?

Comment: If the link is `http://www.example.com/foo/` then no trimming is necessary, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url.match(/http://[\w.]+(?:/[^/]+/)?/);

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to remove everything after the last slash, so replace `[^/]+$` with an empty string.

Comment: This won't work for all URLs.

Comment: There could be more depth (ie: http://example.com/foo/bar/biz/baz?foo